# Is there a way to specify library size when using arcticdb with lmdb?

Tags: python, database, lmdb, arcticdb

I am working on a program which use arcticdb with a local instance of lmdb. During this process I want to create multiple libraries based on different types of data. As the size of the data will differ I want the library size to also be different, but as best as I can tell the library size mimics the map size when creating the orignal database connection. I have defined a minimal code based recreation of the problem below:

```
from arcticdb import Arctic
#Define arctic instance
ac = Arctic("lmdb://" + getcwd() + "/database?map_size=2GB")
#Create libraries
ac.create_library('test1')
ac.create_library('test2')
```

This will result in the following structure:

```
database
|__arctic_cfg
|_test1
| |_data.mdb ~2GB
| |_lock.mdb
|_test2
  |_data.mdb ~2GB
  |_lock.mdb
```

As can be seen each library will take the orignal map size, whereas in my program I want some libraries to be eg 100MB, others to be 20MB and so on. How can I achieve that?

I looked into the documentation and cannot gain any insight from there, one approach would perhaps be a master class with multiple arctic instances but then they would connect to different arctic_cfg folders and be tricky to interact with as I understand.